# How do I monitor changes to an Outlook contacts folder within a public folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, public-folders

I need to monitor changes to an Outlook contacts folder within a public folder. I need to know the field(s) modified and the individual who modified it. More so, if one were to create or delete an entry, I should be notified.

Preferably, I need to be notified via e-mail once a change has occurred.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This will be an option that's set at the server level.  Talk to your email server (presumably Exchange) admin, and they'll likely be able to set this up for you.